# Adding Google AdMob as gradle dependency for a new React Native app flags app as malware

Tags: android, react-native, security, gradle, admob

I'm trying to add Google AdMob to my React Native application which leads to being reported on Android by Comodo Mobile Security Antivirus as malware (malicious behavior).

I've tried the following:

- Adding the library as Gradle dependency in the native Android project doesn't lead to the same problem.
- Adding the library to older React Native versions (< 0.57) doesn't lead to the same problem.
- Adding any version of the library to even a brand new React Native application does lead to being reported as Malware.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'

}
```

I'm trying to not being reported by the Comodo Mobile Security Antivirus as the library itself doesn't seem to be Malicious as I described.

Comment: Is that warning after scanning result ?

Comment: @RAHULJOSHI this shows if you have scanned for results. Also, if you have perviously installed Comodo Mobile Security Antivirus opened it and given it needed permissions and installed your app